# How to resolve exception: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

I am getting this exception in a Blazor Server-Side app when a UI component is called from an async method. More specifically, the app is getting data from the database, and when it is done, it calls a Toast component at which time the exception is thrown:

This is the code that throws the exception:

```
ToastModel model = new ToastModel() { Content = message.MessageToShow, Timeout = message.Timeout};
this.ToastObj.Show(model);
```

This is the exception:

```
[2021-01-19T11:35:49.358Z] Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Dispatcher.AssertAccess()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Notifications.SfToast.Show(ToastModel toastModel)
   at CDS.Pages.Accounts.AccountsView.HandleAsync(StatusBarMessage message) in C:\Dev\cds-order-entry.visualstudio.com\CDSBlazor\CDS\CDS\Pages\Accounts\AccountsView.razor.cs:line 43
   at CDS.Core.EventAggregator.EventAggregator.PublishAsync(Object message) in C:\Dev\cds-order-entry.visualstudio.com\CDSBlazor\CDS\CDS\Core\EventAggregator\EventAggregator.cs:line 78
   at CDS.Pages.Accounts.Search.SearchView.ShowMessage(String message) in C:\Dev\cds-order-entry.visualstudio.com\CDSBlazor\CDS\CDS\Pages\Accounts\Search\SearchView.razor.cs:line 1916
   at CDS.Pages.Accounts.Search.SearchView.DoSearch() in C:\Dev\cds-order-entry.visualstudio.com\CDSBlazor\CDS\CDS\Pages\Accounts\Search\SearchView.razor.cs:line 1397
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Internal.SfBaseUtils.InvokeEvent[T](Object eventFn, T eventArgs)
   at Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons.SfButton.OnClickHandler(MouseEventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

Note that this exception only occurred when the app was published to IIS.  When running in VS, the exception is not thrown.

(Note: This will be self-answered.  It took me much time to debug this, and I want to make it easier for the next guy.)

Answer (score 3):

The fix is actually very easy:  Just wrap it in InvokeAysnc like this:

```
InvokeAsync(() =>
{
    this.ToastObj.Show(model);
});
```

This method is ONLY available on the ComponentBase call, meaning it must be called from the codebehind of the page.

The exception message actually says exactly what the issue is: *Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.*

The moral of the story is that if you are in an async method, wrap any rendering or component state change in InvokeAsync to ensure it is executed on the UI thread, not a background thread.